# Database - Connection is not available

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, prisma

I set up Prisma:1.27 for a new MySQL:5.7 database by following the [Get Started](https://www.prisma.io/docs/get-started/01-setting-up-prisma-new-database-JAVASCRIPT-a002/) tutorial. Prisma doesn't run on http://localhost:4466/ and 
I didn't make any changes to docker-compose.yml in the tutorial.

Error on `docker logs backend_prisma_1`

```
No log level set, defaulting to INFO.
[INFO] {} - Started.
[INFO] {} - Started.
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: database - Connection is not available, request timed out after 5000ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:548)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:186)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:145)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:83)
        at slick.jdbc.hikaricp.HikariCPJdbcDataSource.createConnection(HikariCPJdbcDataSource.scala:14)
        at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.<init>(JdbcBackend.scala:453)
        at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.createSession(JdbcBackend.scala:46)
        at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.createSession(JdbcBackend.scala:37)
        at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef.acquireSession(BasicBackend.scala:249)
        at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef.acquireSession$(BasicBackend.scala:248)
        at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.acquireSession(JdbcBackend.scala:37)
        at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.run(BasicBackend.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=mysql)(port=3306)(type=master) : Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:161)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.connException(ExceptionMapper.java:79)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1040)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:490)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:144)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:90)
        at slick.jdbc.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.scala:101)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:341)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:193)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:430)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$500(HikariPool.java:64)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:570)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:563)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:398)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1032)
        ... 14 more
```

docker logs backend_mysql_1

```
M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-03-03T05:55:34.059073Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-03-03T05:55:34.061007Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2019-03-03T05:55:34.072210Z 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Table flags are 0 in the data dictionary but the flags in file ./ibdata1 are 0x4800!
2019-03-03 05:55:34 0x7f25c2567740  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139800150964032 in file ut0ut.cc line 942
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
05:55:34 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 68196 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2c)[0x55b550a9381c]
mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x479)[0x55b5503be879]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x110c0)[0x7f25c21450c0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xcf)[0x7f25c08d1fff]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a)[0x7f25c08d342a]
mysqld(+0x628efb)[0x55b550394efb]
mysqld(_ZN2ib5fatalD1Ev+0x12d)[0x55b550c63b9d]
mysqld(+0xfa4901)[0x55b550d10901]
mysqld(+0xfa4f38)[0x55b550d10f38]
mysqld(_Z6fil_ioRK9IORequestbRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmmPvS8_+0x2b0)[0x55b550d1a0f0]
mysqld(_Z13buf_read_pageRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_t+0xce)[0x55b550ccf16e]
mysqld(_Z16buf_page_get_genRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmP11buf_block_tmPKcmP5mtr_tb+0x4aa)[0x55b550c9e3ba]
mysqld(_Z31trx_rseg_get_n_undo_tablespacesPm+0x143)[0x55b550c41d33]
mysqld(+0x62806f)[0x55b55039406f]
mysqld(_Z34innobase_start_or_create_for_mysqlv+0x2f3d)[0x55b550c0ebed]
mysqld(+0xd6e963)[0x55b550ada963]
mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x4f)[0x55b55040959f]
mysqld(+0xb14e16)[0x55b550880e16]
mysqld(_Z40plugin_register_builtin_and_init_core_sePiPPc+0x2f0)[0x55b550884000]
mysqld(+0x64af7e)[0x55b5503b6f7e]
mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0xc71)[0x55b5503b8b41]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1)[0x7f25c08bf2e1]
mysqld(_start+0x2a)[0x55b5503af21a]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2019-03-03T05:56:35.267390Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-03-03T05:56:35.268644Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.25) starting as process 1 ...
2019-03-03T05:56:35.271475Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2019-03-03T05:56:35.271519Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-03-03T05:56:35.271525Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-03-03T05:56:35.271529Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2019-03-03T05:56:35.271533Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-03-03T05:56:35.271536Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-03-03T05:56:35.271709Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-03-03T05:56:35.271820Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-03-03T05:56:35.273305Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-03-03T05:56:35.279100Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-03-03T05:56:35.280747Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2019-03-03T05:56:35.291980Z 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Table flags are 0 in the data dictionary but the flags in file ./ibdata1 are 0x4800!
2019-03-03 05:56:35 0x7f1afdaee740  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139753901975360 in file ut0ut.cc line 942
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
05:56:35 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.
```

docker ps (**For some reason no port is allocated to the mysql container**)

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS                    NAMES
8289d0817837        mysql:5.7                   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   14 minutes ago      Restarting (2) 43 seconds ago                            backend_mysql_1
76aba55bffd4        prismagraphql/prisma:1.27   "/bin/sh -c /app/sta…"   14 minutes ago      Up 6 seconds                    0.0.0.0:4466->4466/tcp   backend_prisma_1
```

docker-compose ps

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
      Name                   Command               State              Ports
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
backend_mysql_1    docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld   Restarting
backend_prisma_1   /bin/sh -c /app/start.sh      Up           0.0.0.0:4466->4466/tcp
```

Comment: mysql is failing that's why there are no ports assigned. what is the output of `docker logs backend_mysql_1` ?

Comment: @MostafaHussein I just added the logs for backend_mysql_1

Comment: can you try to remote ib* files from `/var/lib/mysql` and recreate the contaienr again ?

Answer (score -1):

This issue was solved in Prisma 1.28.0